# How to change key in nested dictionary in Javacript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, key

in coding world, I have a data in format of

```
knownMessages : {
    topic:string, 
    messages: Array<{
        key: string;
        value;
        sum_num: number;
        headers: Map<string, string>;
    }>;
}[]
```

if i have

```
knownMessages = {topic:"some_topic", messages: [{"network type":"lan"}, {"agent": "aman"},{    "my ed":"btech"}]}
```

How can i changes keys such that it removes space like key "network type" is "network-type" and also add it back to dictionary

```
{"network-type": "lan", {"agent": "aman"}, {"my-ed": "btech"}}
```

```
for(let i = 0; i < knownMessages.messages.length; i++){
    if(knownMessages.message[i][key].include(" ")){
        const newKey = key.replace(/\s+/g, "-");
        knownMessages.messages[i][newKey] = value;
        delete topicMessage.messages[i][key]
    }
}
```

This is giving me errors, i dont know javaScript and dont know how to access keys.

Comment: You need to iterate the `Object.keys()`. (also `-` is no more valid in an object property than ` ` is, you'll want `_` or camelCase)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove the space in keys in a nested object using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537182/remove-the-space-in-keys-in-a-nested-object-using-javascript)

Comment: @pilchard hello pilchard first of all thank you for your answer i saw that question that is nested object, but here in my case it is an object which is part of array which is in object,  {  , [ { k,v } ,{k,v } ] }, now here i have to change key. So I'll look into that questions solution see if I can mould it, but i am absolute beginner if you could help please tell how could that be moulded for this particular case.

Comment: The data for your `messages` array and the **format** appear to mismatch. For example, in the **format** each element of the `messages` array has 4 props namely: `key`, `value`, `sum_num` and `headers` - but in your data, the elements of `message` array have none of the 4 props.

Comment: @jsN00b sorry for making it confusing actually i have to particularly change values for objects inside array, and hence  i only provided full values, would make edit that, anyways thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work

it will be better to add '_' or rename it to camalcase

```
knownMessages = {topic:"some_topic",
                 messages: [
                   {"network type":"lan"},
                   {"agent": "aman"},
                   {    "my ed":"btech"}
                 ]
                }

console.log(knownMessages)
for(let i = 0; i < knownMessages.messages.length; i++){
   key =Object.keys(knownMessages.messages[i])[0]


    if(key.includes(" ")){
    const newKey = key.replace(/\s+/g, "_");  
    knownMessages.messages[i][newKey] = knownMessages.messages[i]key]
    delete knownMessages.messages[i][key]
    }
}
console.log(knownMessages)
```

**before**

```
Object { topic: "some_topic", messages: Array [Object { network type: "lan" }, Object { agent: "aman" }, Object { my ed: "btech" }] }
```

**after**

```
Object { topic: "some_topic", messages: Array [Object { network-type: "lan" }, Object { agent: "aman" }, Object { my-ed: "btech" }] }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am extremely greatful for your answer, it solved issue that i definately wouldn't have been able to do on my own thanks alot.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much more simpler just to do: `newMessages =  knownMessages.messages.map(obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(([k, v]) => (k.includes(' ') ? [k.replaceAll(' ', '_'), v] : [k, v] ))));`. This one line code will also not mutate the original `messages` and instead create a new array (keeping the original as-is). This can be either use to mutate `knownMessages` object - or a new object `newKnownMessages` can also be constructed.

Comment: `network-type` is not a valid property name without quotes